# Finding the complement value for an event?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $P(AB) = 0.7$, $P(A) = .20$, and $P(A\cup B) = .45$. What is the output for $P(AB^c)$?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. And is there anything we know about $P(\overline{X})$, if we know $P(X)$?

Comment: I just need the formula for P(ABComplement)

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is why we need you to use MathJax: What is ABComplement ?  $A\cap B^\complement$ or $(A\cap B)^\complement$ .  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the idea - and I'll leave it to you to plug and chug.

To count $A \setminus B = A \cap B^C$ we have

$$ |A \setminus B| = |A| - |A \cap B| $$

A similar formula holds for probabilities. Can you take it from here?